# Searching multiple Postcodes in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with 8000 records that i would like to search by postcode. 
This is my client list and i would like to say search for all clients living in the "EH1","EH2","KY1","SW9" postcodes.
I would like the search to return all the values related to that postcode.

The excel document is laid out like this.
(ID,Name,Surname,Address,Postcode,Telephone Number)
Im a novice at excel spreadsheets so any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
ID      Name    Surname   Address             Postcode  Telephone number
26584   John    Smith     69 Bedford road     Eh12 5db  0131225689
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited with quick and dirty method:

If you only need to use this table a few times, then there is a quick and dirty method:

Make a helper column that only includes the first 3 characters of the postcode. You do this via the [left function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/left-leftb-functions-HP005209153.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP005204211), specifying the postcode column in the first argument, then "3" in the next, to return the first 3 characters. This effectively hides the values you haven't ticked.

You then use the filter section at the top of the column once you have made it a table as stated earlier. In the drop down menu untick "Select all", then tick the values you want to see, i.e. the postcodes you are interested in).

You can then copy the *visible cells only* via [Copy visible cells only](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/copy-visible-cells-only-HA010244897.aspx) if you want to use just that list.

A longer, but more robust method would involve three tables. The first is your data set as it is, with the helper column as discused above included. The second would be a simple single column of all the first three letter codes you are interested in. The third would be an array function modified from this formula:

```
=index($a$1:$b$7,small(if($a$1:$a$7=$a$10,ROW($a$1:$a$7)),ROW(1:1)),2)
```

which returns multiple items based on preset criteria, ignoring those that are not specified. I would link to a site explaining this better but I am such a new user I can hardly do anything it seems :(

Comment: Dave I don't want to filter the contents i want to find multiple entries in a query filtering doesnt give you the option to find  "EH1","EH2","KY1","SW9" unless you individually type each search parameter i.e EH1 then EH2 then ect ect. I have tons of searching to do and would have to sift through 8000 records.

Comment: So you are effctively wanting to use the existing table as a data base, and elsewhere (for instance another sheet), have a feature where you input multiple area codes, and view the output in a separate list, which excludes those results you have not searched for?

Comment: If you only need to use this table a few times, then there is a quick and dirty method:

Make a helper column that only includes the first 3 characters of the postcode. You do this via the [left function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/left-leftb-functions-HP005209153.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP005204211), specifying the postcode column in the first argument, then "3" in the next, to return the first 3 characters.

Comment: Can you share the quick and dirty method Dave

Comment: Edited original due to character limit of comments

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you simply use an autofilter on the respective column.

Here is a short tutorial for Excel 2010: [AUTOFILTER TUTORIAL](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/quick-start-filter-data-by-using-an-autofilter-HA010370616.aspx)

Comment: I have to search for about 75 different postcodes this will only search for individual postcodes i.e EH54 will bring back 6 results but i want to be able to specify multiple searches like "EH1","EH2","KY1","SW9"

Comment: Excel 2010 and later will filter on multiple criteria, but you have to do it one by one. Excel 2007 and earlier don't have this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I think an easy way to do this is first make Postcode column first; from Column E to Column A.
Insert a new column in Column A, then use the left function to get the first 3 characters of the postcode: =LEFT(B1,3)

With this, you can use VLOOKUP to search for the postcodes "EH1","EH2","KY1","SW9", and use multiple VLOOKUP formulas to return a column index of everything.

You'll end up with a list of everything for that specific postcode.